# iPhone - Line spacing method similar to CGContextSetCharacterSpacing

Tags: iphone, cgcontext

In my UITextView, i'm using custom label.
In draw rect method i'm using CGContextSetCharacterSpacing to set the spacing between characters.
Is there any method to set the line spacing similar to CGContextSetCharacterSpacing?
Or else how can I set line spacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed text view by web view and I created HTML file. Then in html I adjusted the line height by style sheet.